# Anonymous likes for elements

Tags: plugins

Can anyone help direct me to a plugin or way of anonymously liking articles?

I have used the Like plugin by Duct (https://dukt.net/craft/like) but unfortunately it must be associated to a user account to save the entry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's ["Upvote"](https://craftpl.us/plugins/upvote) by Lindsey DiLoreto, which allows anonymous voting. Not sure though, if it makes use of cookies and/or logging of IP addresses to forbid people (read: make it harder for them) to vote multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for the shout-out @carlcs! Yes, you can indeed ["like" anonymously with Upvote](https://craftpl.us/plugins/upvote/docs/plugin-settings). It uses a simple cookie method of tracking votes, so security against duplicate voting is pretty minimal. That being said, don't be under the false impression that IP tracking will solve that problem either. IP tracking [can be beaten just as easily](https://www.buyonlinecontestvotes.com/ip-votes.html). The only real security is requiring users to login to your website.

Comment: If your users have nothing to gain by cheating (ie: just "liking" articles), then cookie-based anonymous voting is fine... But if you are running some sort of contest, then anonymous voting (in any form) is a terrible idea.

Comment: That was perfect for the job, many thanks :)